# IE homepage set to some site I don't know about

Tags: windows-vista, internet-explorer-8, virus

Looks like I have some kind of virus on my computer. The default home page for Internet Explorer keeps getting set to some site called `socio.fusionace.com`

Gmail has also been giving me problems in the past few days. I have to view it in HTML mode.

I don't have an antivirus installed.

Comment: Before seeing a flow of "I recommend you this antivirus", with everyone's flavor, keep in mind that there is a question about free antivirus which can be found there: http://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would definitely run a virus scanner nowadays and would recommend the Free edition of [AVG](http://free.avg.com/gb-en/homepage)

I have used this one for years and have been very happy with it.

Answer (score 4):

Homepage hijacking is most certainly an indicator for a malware attack.

First, run **[MBAM](http://www.malwarebytes.org/mbam.php)**  (quick scan will usually suffice), then scan your computer thoroughly for viruses.

If you're looking for a 'non-resident' virus (and malware) scanner, i recommend **[a-squared FREE](http://www.emsisoft.com/en/software/free/)**.

Answer (score 1):

Once you get the virus/malware problem solved you may still have problems with homepage/link hijacking. You may want to check out the software [WinSockFix](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Tweak/Network-Tweak/WinSockFix.shtml) as it should help resolve that problem. Depending on what kind of infection you have (and no disrespect to this site), check out the [security](http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/Security-f118.html) section of GeeksToGo.com as they have been incredibly helpful for an issue I dealt with in the past.