# Browser keeps setting itself to assistmypc.org - What's up with that?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, virus, homepage

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [IE homepage set to some site I don’t know about](https://superuser.com/questions/71233/ie-homepage-set-to-some-site-i-dont-know-about)

Originally I set my IE 8 home page as Google.
After some time, it's been changed to `http://assistmypc.org`

This keeps happening all the time.

Could this be due to a virus running on my PC?

Comment: are you asking "how programmatically was your browser's home page set? Or were you asking "my browsers home page was set, do I have a virus?" One can be related to SO and one is not.

Comment: » If your question is about … general computer software or hardware troubleshooting, ask on Super User.« – from the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq). Just wait a while and the question should get migrated.

Comment: This is a notorious spyware issue.  You should be running some anti-spyware software to remove the offending nuisance.  Check into MalwareBytes, Microsoft Security Essentials or Spybot Search & Destroy

Answer (score 3):

Whilst it can be numerous things, it most likely is down to a virus.

My general advise for similar situations:

Start with a good tool such as [Spybot Search and Destroy](http://www.safer-networking.org/index2.html) or [Malwarebytes Anti Malware](http://www.malwarebytes.org/) and perform a full scan.

After this has finished, use [Microsoft / Sysinternals Autoruns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) and look through most of the tabs (you especially want to pay close attention to `Logon` and `Scheduled tasks`) and delete most of the items that you think are viruses or research them first.

Next, protect your system with a good antivirus. I personally recommend [Microsoft Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/Security_Essentials/).

Comment: +1 for this. Plus, be sure to turn off System restore if you are using an OS that supports it. Much malware has a way of "hiding" in the system restore area and restoring itself after a reboot

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to any legitimate program too but mostly this is done by spyware and other types of programs and toolbars. I would recommend to run a spyware test on your computer by downloading any anti-spyware software.

Answer (score 0):

It probably is a virus. (or spyware)